# Linear Graph Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

So I have a linear graph:

[image]

By the graph itself, we can see it decreasing. But if we take these points: $(0,2)$ and $(4,0)$ we get $\frac{1}{2}$. I thought you can take any $2$ points on a linear graph to get a correct slope, why is it in this case not accurate? Obviously we can take $(0,2)$ and $(2,1)$ and get to the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle\frac{0-2}{4-0}=-\frac12$, not $\dfrac12$.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that.. thanks Jose.

Comment: @EliS. If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Yeah there is a time limit, it said I have to wait 10 min before, 25seconds left.